# What does $\cong$ mean when considering two random variables?

Tags: probability, notation

I encounter the $\cong$ sign when reading a book on probability, however I'm not sure about its exact meaning:

(Bryc W. The normal distribution: characterizations with applications[M]. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.)
[image]

Does $X\cong Y$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables) means X and Y have the same distribution?

Comment: Note that if the distribution of $a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2 + \dots a_n X_n$ is the same for all $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ with $\sum_i a_i^2 = 1$, then in particular $a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2 + \dots a_n X_n$ has the same distribution as $X_1$ (take $a_1 = 1$ and $a_i = 0$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$), so your guess seems to be quite reasonable to me. I have seen "~" being frequently used in this context which looks quite similar to "$\cong$".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those notation usually denotes having same distribution

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/672848)

Comment: ah thank you, I am new in this forum